# Differential equations, integral equations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Is there an analytical way of proving that if $\phi$ is a solution to
\begin{equation} y(t)=e^{it}+a\int_{t}^{\infty}\sin (t-s)y(s)s^{-2}ds,
\end{equation}
then $\phi$ would be a solution to the differential equation
\begin{equation}
y''+(1+at^{-2})y=0\quad ?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you advance. We have

> $$ \begin{equation} y(t)=e^{it}+a\int_{t}^{\infty}\sin (t-s)y(s)s^{-2}ds,
> \end{equation}. $$

Now, differentiating the above equation twice with respect to $t$ yields

> $$y''= -e^{it} - a  \int _{t}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\sin \left( t-s \right) y
>  \left( s \right) }{{s}^{2}}}{ds}-a{\frac {y \left( t \right) }{{t}^{2}
> }}  .$$

Adding the two equations and simplifying gives you the desired result. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662685/differentiating-a-convolution-integral/662710#662710).

**Note:** For differentiating under the integral sign, we need the [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

> $$ \frac{d}{dx} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt \right) = f(x,b(x))\,b'(x) - f(x,a(x))\,a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f_x(x,t)\; dt. $$

Comment: I might be wrong but doesn't the fact that the integral is improper pose a problem for the Leibniz rule to be used?

Comment: @Ni k: Read the theorem and see if you have a problem.