# Differentiating a convolution integral

Tags: calculus, convolution, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I'm trying to turn the integro-differential equation

$\phi'(t) + \phi(t) = \int_0^t \sin{(t - \xi)} \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi}$

into the differential equation

$\phi'''(t) + \phi''(t) + \phi'(t) = 0$

through differentiation.

I noticed that $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \left( \sin{t} \ast \phi(t) \right) = \left( \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \sin{t} \right) \ast \phi(t) = -\sin{t} \ast \phi(t)$, which gives us the equation:

$\phi'''(t) + \phi''(t) = \int_0^t (-\sin{(t - \xi)}) \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi} = - \int_0^t \sin{(t-\xi)} \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi} = -(\phi'(t) + \phi(t))$

Then we can rewrite this as

$\phi'''(t) + \phi''(t) + \phi'(t) + \phi(t) = 0$, which is almost what I want except for the $\phi(t)$ term.

Is this the right way of going about it or should I be trying something else?

Comment: Your differentiation is not right.  Note that the integral bounds also depend on t.

Comment: See a [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408777/volterra-integral-equation-with-variable-boundaries). You can use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648512/differential-equations-integral-equations/648526#648526) too.

Comment: Note that, if you differentiate the $ \int_0^t \sin{(t - \xi)} \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi}  $ twice you should get $ -\int_0^t \sin{(t - \xi)} \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi} + \phi(t)  $ which is your mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach. If you use this [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648512/differential-equations-integral-equations/648526#648526), then it is easy to derive the result. We use the Leibniz's rule, for differentiating under the integral sign, to differentiate the equation

> $$ \phi'(t) + \phi(t) = \int_0^t \sin{(t - \xi)} \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi} \longrightarrow (1)$$

twice which gives

> $$ \phi'''(t) + \phi''(t) = -\int_0^t \sin{(t - \xi)} \, \phi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} {\xi} + \phi(t)  \longrightarrow (2).$$

Adding the two equations yields

> $$ \phi'''(t) + \phi''(t)+\phi'(t)=0. $$